# C++ pure virtual methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

Consider this demo program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual int f(int) =0;
    virtual int f(){ return f(0); }

    virtual ~Base(){ }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int f(int i)
    {
        return (10 + i);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Derived obj;
    printf("%d\n", obj.f(1));  // This works, and returns 11
    printf("%d\n", obj.f());   // Adding this line gives me the error listed below
}
```

Which gives me the following compilation error:

```
virtualfunc.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
virtualfunc.cpp:25:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::f()’
virtualfunc.cpp:15:9: note: candidate is: virtual int Derived::f(int)
```

My hope was that a call to `obj.f()` would result in a call to `Base::obj.f()` since the derived class doesn't define it, which would then result in a call to `Derived::obj.f(0)` per the definition in class Base.

What am I doing wrong here?  Is there a way to accomplish this?  Specifically, I'd like the call to `obj.f()` to return 10.

(Also please note that I realize I could use a default argument to solve this, but this code is simply a concise example of my issue, so please don't tell me to use default arguments.)

Thanks.

Comment: The `f` function in `Derived` `hides` the other functions, defined in `Base`. That's why you get this error

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585913/c-member-function-virtual-override-and-overload-at-the-same-time

Comment: @Kiril Kirov, You win -- if you want to answer this, I'll mark it as correct.  Explicitly adding `using Base::f;` in the Derived class definition fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: @raj -- Yes it appears to be; I apologize.  I actually sifted through 20 or so questions that didn't answer mine and didn't come across this one.

Comment: @jedwards - I'm glad, that I helped. I added my answer (:

Comment: Also note that [this FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9) addresses this exact issue, sadly I didn't get that warning so I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @jedwards - Is there any reason why you are declaring base class member functions as **virtual** here ? Or is it just a future proof where the base class pointer points to the derived type situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, that the defined `f` (in `Derived` ) `hides` the `f` functions from the `Base` class. The solution is to add `using`. Like this:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int f(int i)
    {
        return (10 + i);
    }

//  vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    using Base::f;
};
```

Answer (score 8):

The issue you're running into is orthogonal to pure virtual functions and has to do with how C++ does name resolution in class hierarchies.

When you write

```
obj.f();
```

C++ tries to look for a function named `f` so it knows what to call.  Since `obj` is of type `Derived`, it starts inside of `Derived` and looks for a function called `f`.  It ends up finding `Derived::f(int)`, and even though this function takes an argument, C++ thinks this is the method you're trying to call and thus stops looking.  The compiler then notices that you're trying to invoke it with no parameters, giving you the error about the function call.

To fix this, you need to tell the C++ compiler that it also needs to try looking for the function `Base::f()`, which is contained in the base class.  To do this, you can change your definition of `Derived` as follows:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int f(int i)
    {
        return (10 + i);
    }

    using Base::f;
};
```

This line `using Base::f` tells C++ that it should treat functions in `Base` named `f` as though they are part of `Derived`.  That way, when the compiler tries looking up a function named `f`, it finds both `Derived::f(int)` and `Base::f()`.  The call will then succeed because the compiler can figure out that you're trying to call `Base::f()` with the code that you've listed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `f(int)` in the derived class hides the name of `Base::f` which you didn't override. All you need to do is to unhide this by writing `using Base::f;`in the derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    using Base::f;   //note this line!

    int f(int i)
    {
        return (10 + i);
    }
};
```

Comment: @Mahesh: This is nothing to do with virtual mechanism, because he is using object of derived type.

Comment: I don't see any specific use of virtual here.