# XCode compilation error for C++ code

Tags: iphone, c++, compilation

I am trying to use my C++ classes for an iPhone app. I got 2 compilation errors in XCode that I do not quite understand. Here is the first one, in this header file myApps.h, I declare a `class myApps` and a `struct PointF`:

```
#pragma once
struct PointF {
    float x;
    float y;
};   // **compilation error message here :Multiple types in one declaration**

class myClass   { 
...
}
```

The second error is in a header file too,

```
#pragma once
class myClass1;
class myClass2;

class MyClass   
{
public:
  MyClass(void *view);
 ~MyClass();  

  virtual void Draw(myClass1 *c1); 
 //Error: Candidate is virtual void MyClass::Draw(myClass1 *)

  virtual void Move(myClass2 c2[], myClass1 *c1, void *callback);
  //Error: Candidate is virtual void MyClass::Move((myClass2, myClass1*, void*)
};
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you sure it's not generating error in some cpp file and then refer to these locations?

Comment: Please use proper formatting using `{}` seen above your edit box. Also make the question clearer.

Comment: You say you declare `class myApps`, you go and declare `class myClass`, and in the other file you declare `class MyClass`. Is this the exact code that causes you the problem?

Comment: What does the translation unit look like? These errors are almost always caused by a missing semicolon in a class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't know if this will help you but, from what I see:

myClass should have a semicolon at the end:

```
class myClass   { 
...
};
```

For the `Candidate is virtual void MyClass::Draw(myClass1 *)` below the last function of your class:

```
using myClass1::Draw;
using myClass1::Move;
```

since you probably have a method Draw and Move in myClass1... [More on it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233085/c-help-with-pure-virtual-methods) It's hard to figure out exactly since I can't see the stuff in myClass1 and myClass2.

Answer (score 0):

Just check Whether your file extension is .m or .mm for C++ files it must be .mm extension.