# Calling overrided virtual function instead of overloaded

Tags: c++, overriding, overloading

Say i have this part of code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    virtual int f(const A& other) const { return 1; }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    int f(const A& other) const { return 2; }
    virtual int f(const B& other) const { return 3; }
};

void go(const A& a, const A& a1, const B& b) {
    cout << a1.f(a) << endl; //Prints 2
    cout << a1.f(a1) << endl; //Prints 2
    cout << a1.f(b) << endl; //Prints 2
}
int main() {
    go(A(), B(), B());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I can understand why the first two will print 2. But I cannot understand why the last print is also 2. Why doesn't it prefers the overloaded function in `B`?

I already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530616/override-on-non-virtual-functions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585913/c-member-function-virtual-override-and-overload-at-the-same-time) but I couldn't manage to understand from these.

Comment: Because you are using an `A` reference to call `f`. And `A` has no knowledge of `f(const B& other)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int B::f(const B& other) const` doesn't [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#In_detail) `int A::f(const A& other) const` because the parameter type is not the same. Then it won't be called via calling `f()` on reference of the base class `A`.

> If some member function vf is declared as virtual in a
>   class Base, and some class Derived, which is derived, directly or
>   indirectly, from Base, has a declaration for member function with the
>   same
>
> ```
> name
> parameter type list (but not the return type)
> cv-qualifiers
> ref-qualifiers
> ```
>
> Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual (whether or
>   not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration) and *overrides*
>   Base::vf (whether or not the word override is used in its
>   declaration).

If you use [override specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) (since C++11) compiler will generate the error.

```
class B : public A {
public:
    int f(const A& other) const { return 2; }
    virtual int f(const B& other) const override { return 3; }
};
```

Such as [Clang](http://rextester.com/BOIMX66399):

```
source_file.cpp:10:17: error: 'f' marked 'override' but does not override any member functions
    virtual int f(const B& other) const override { return 3; }
                ^
```

If you add an overload for it in the base class, you might get what you want. Note that a forward declaration of class `B` will be needed.

```
class B;
class A {
public:
    virtual int f(const A& other) const { return 1; }
    virtual int f(const B& other) const { return 1; }
};
```

<kbd>[LIVE](http://rextester.com/KRAWT94911)</kbd>

Comment: Makes sense, combining this with @ArmenTsirunyan `vtable` explanation I perfectly understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, really. You're calling `f` on an object with static type `A`. `A` has only one `f`, so there's only one entry in the `vtable` for that function. Overload resolution takes place compile-time. The overload will only be resolved if you call it on an object whose **static** type is `B`

Answer (score 0):

The confusion comes in that your:

`int f(const A& other) const { return 2; }`

line is actually virtual also and is overriding your line:

`virtual int f(const A& other) const { return 1; }`

Meanwhile, the line:

`virtual int f(const B& other) const { return 3; }`

ends up being completely ignored because everything matches to the "return 1" line, then follows polymorphically up the chain to the "return 2" line.  As the other poster said, the `const B` portion means it won't match the polymorphic method call.

As an aside:  If you're getting a 2 on the first line, I'm suspicious of undesired stack behavior.  I'd expect a 1.  Perhaps try allocating like this:

```
A a1;
B b1, b2;

go(a1, b1, b2);
```