# Virtual function overloading and signature

Tags: virtual, overloading

I thought that since f's argument is float - the float version of **f** will be called, but that's not the case. Why is it?

Thank you!

```
  class A
{
public: virtual void f(int n)
    {

        cout<<"A"<<endl;

    }
};

class B: public A
{
public: virtual void f(float f)
    {
        cout<<"B"<<endl;

    }
};

 int main()
{
A* ptr = new B;
ptr->f(6.66);
delete ptr;
}
```

Comment: The function signature for `B::f` is different than `A::f` which means that they are two different functions and `B::f` *hides* `A::f`. The original pointer `A* ptr = new B;` is of type `A`. So, when calling the `f` function, it first looks in class `A` to see if there is a possible match. It sees `A::f(int)` and does an integer conversion. (See [this example](http://ideone.com/MxIJ9q).)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling overrided virtual function instead of overloaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096552/calling-overrided-virtual-function-instead-of-overloaded)